# Codename One - how to add function to existing web service

Tags: web-services, codenameone

with the CN1 web service wizard, I created a working server project that I run on my local Tomcat installation. in addition, the CN1 project has the webserviceproxy.java class that I use to call the web services. so far so good.

During development, there now is the need to create a new function within the webservice that I did not previously think of. So instead of recreating my whole server using the wizard, I thought I simply add some code into the files that were created.

On the client side:

WebServiceProxy.java - add WebServiceProxyCall.WSDefinition and add the function call in sync and async fashion. the arguments and return type matches the definition.

On the server side:

WebServiceProxyServer.java 
- add the function definition with the required functionality (this works as I have it debugged it locally on the server side).

CN1WebServiceServlet.java - add definition and add the if statement matching the service name.

when debugging the server and calling the service from the client, it does not reach the breakpoint of the doPost method, so something is terribly off.

What else do I need to change when manually adding a new webservice function? Or is this so complicated that I should better use the web service wizard, create the new server from scratch and copy all the other functionality from my old server to the new one?

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this seamlessly since the generated protocol is binary for fastest protocol performance.

The solution is to generate a new class we usually use the notion V2, V3 onward. That way the first webservice is still 100% compatible to devices in production and you can create a new "more correct" protocol for the newer devices. The implementation classes can derive from one another to increase code reuse.